# Javascript reduce initialValue is empty object, what's the meaning of it?

Tags: javascript

In MDN [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) , what's the meaning of `allNames[name]`?  `allNames` should be `{}` first, but if object is empty, `allNames[name] = 1` equal to `{}['Alice'] = 1` ? how can it become `{ 'Alice': 1}`,
I'm so confused.

```
Counting instances of values in an object

var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

var countedNames = names.reduce(function (allNames, name) { 
  if (name in allNames) {
    allNames[name]++;
  }
  else {
    allNames[name] = 1;
  }
  return allNames;
}, {});
// countedNames is:
// { 'Alice': 2, 'Bob': 1, 'Tiff': 1, 'Bruce': 1 }
```

Comment: The initial object is what you start with and what gets returned.

Comment: `allNames[name] = 1` adds the content of `name` as a new property to `allNames` and immediately stores the value `1` in that newly added property -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Can you provide the link for the MDN page you're talking about? It looks like allNames[name] is a control variable to count how many times a name is found.

Comment: this is the syntax of reduce,
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue]), you cant do any reduce operation when the array is empty.

Comment: Break it down. `{}['Alice`] = 1`; `{}` is an empty object. `['Alice']` gets or sets the property named "Alice" on that object (in this case, because of the `= 1`, it's setting). `= 1` sets the property to 1. So the outcome of that operation is an object with an Alice property equal to 1, or `{ Alice: 1 }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is an aggregation or accumulator function. This means it takes a collection of items (`names`) and boils it down to a single "accumulated" value (`allNames`).

```js
names.reduce(function (allNames, name) {  // `allNames` is the accumulated value, `name` is the current item in `names`
  if (name in allNames) {
    allNames[name]++;
  }
  else {
    allNames[name] = 1;
  }
  return allNames;
}, {}); // The empty object here is the initial value of the accumulated value
```

So this function creates an accumulated value that is an object with a key corresponding to each name in `names`, and values corresponding to the frequency of that `name` in `names`.

Finally: note that objects have an index notation for property access/creation (*very* similar to arrays!). So the following means "if such a property does not already exist on object `allNames`, create a property with a name that is the value of variable `name`, and assign the value `1` to its value:

```
allNames[name] = 1
```

Comment: thanks,  you're right ! , I knew what's it , it should be bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs you provided:

> The reducer function takes four arguments:
> Accumulator (acc)
> Current Value (cur)
> Current Index (idx)
> Source Array (src)

So the first variable is the accumulator, a variable that will hold accumulated values that you eventually will calculate, like in this example you are accumulating names.

Answer (score -1):

The reduce function above can be rewritten into the following function.

This streamlined version shows that we are modifying the result (starts with `{}`) by incrementing the value for the `name`.

If `result[item]` is undefined, we use zero.

```js
const names = [ 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice' ];

const frequencyMap = (items) => items.reduce((result, item) =>
  ({ ...result, [item]: (result[item] || 0) + 1 }), {});

console.log(frequencyMap(names));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is the really-long version without reduce.

```js
const names = [ 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice' ];

const frequencyMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  const name = names[i],
        prev = frequencyMap[name];
  if (prev !== undefined) {
    frequencyMap[name] += 1; // Increment value by 1
  } else {
    frequencyMap[name] = 1;  // Initial value
  }
}

console.log(frequencyMap);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```